# PowerShell: Use test-path to check for file existence in multiple folders on a netowork share

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to check for the existence of a file in multiple folders on a network share and return the name of the folder in which the file exists. I'm new to PowerShell so thus far, I can check for the existence of the file in one folder on the network share using this line:

```
test-path \\networkshare\folder\file.txt
```

How do I go about building this code out to check for the existence of the file in four other folders on the share and returning the name of the folder that the file exists in?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
[string]$FileName = "file.txt"

$Directories = @("\\networkshare\folder", "\\networkshare\folder2", "\\networkshare\folder3")

$Directories | %{ 
  If (Test-Path ($_ + "\" + $FileName))
  { Write-Host $_ }
}
```

Change Write-Host to whatever you need to do with that folder name.

Comment: For my understanding, let's try something simpler.  I would like to loop through the %directories array and return True/False based on the files existence.  I've tried this: `$Directories | {test-path $Filename}`, but it returns False for all items in the array though I know the file exists in two of the directories

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reason that [`Join-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799.aspx) exists. We can use it to build the path for us.

```
$fileToLocate = "1.log"
$Directories = @("C:\temp", "\\networkshare\folder2", "\\networkshare\folder3")

Join-Path -Path $Directories -ChildPath $fileToLocate | Where-Object{Test-Path $_} | ForEach-Object{
    Write-Host "$fileToLocate found in: $_" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

In the example above `Join-Path -Path $Directories -ChildPath $fileToLocate` would generate a string array like so

```
C:\temp\1.log
\\networkshare\folder2\1.log
\\networkshare\folder3\1.log
```

We then use `Test-Path` to see if any of those exist. If one does then it moves into the `ForEach-Object` block so that it can be output to console with `Write-Host`.